# pydantic: BaseSettings with parametrized default values

Tags: python, pydantic

It appears one cannot create an `__init__` function on pydantic BaseSettings superclasses.

I am trying to achieve this (note; for demonstration, this code is not supported in pydantic):

```
class MySettings(BaseSettings):
    
    def __init__(self, foo: str):
        
        self.p1 = f"{foo}_param_name1"  # <- trying to achieve this 
        self.p2 = f"{foo}_param_name2"  # <- trying to achieve this

    redis_host: Optional[str] = "asdf"

settings = MySettings(foo="test")
assert settings.redis_host == "asdf"
assert settings.p1 == "test_param_name1" # this will raise a ValueError for p1 not existing
assert settings.p2 == "test_param_name2"
```

So far, the closest thing I've found is `create_model` https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation
but this is not discussed in the context of `BaseSettings`

Is there a way to achieve a BaseSettings superclass where some values are set based on a parameter?

The following seems pretty nasty and would also greatly confuse code editors:

```
def retrofit(class_instance: BaseSettings, foo: str):
      setattr(class_instance, "p1", f"{foo}_param_name1")
```

This also works, but causes many linting errors and also confuses editors (seems not to know p1 is a parameter)

```
def default_settings(foo: str) -> Type[BaseSettings]:
    class DefaultSettings(BaseSettings):
        

        p1 = f"{foo}_param_name1"
        redis_host: Optional[str] = "asdf"


    return DefaultSettings


MyDefaultSettings: Type[BaseSettings] = default_settings("test")


class SuperSettings(MyDefaultSettings): # linting error that MyDefaultSettings is not a valid type
    """ """


conf = SuperSettings()
assert conf.p1 == "test_param_name1" # works at runtime, but linting error that p1 is not an attribute
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseSettings` has own constructor `__init__` and if you want to override it you should implement same behavior as original constructor +α.

In other case you may call constructor of base (`super`) class that will do his job. Correct inheritance is matter.

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings
from typing import Optional


class MySettings(BaseSettings):

    p1: Optional[str]
    p2: Optional[str]
    redis_host: Optional[str] = "asdf"

    def __init__(self, *args, foo: str = None, **kwargs):

        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if foo is not None:
            self.p1 = f"{foo}_param_name1"  # <- achieved
            self.p2 = f"{foo}_param_name2"  # <- achieved

settings = MySettings(foo="test")
assert settings.redis_host == "asdf"
assert settings.p1 == "test_param_name1" # no ValueError
assert settings.p2 == "test_param_name2"
```

No assertions in this code

Comment: Is there a reason for `_` instead of defining `foo` as a keyword-only parameter with a default value of `None`? `def __init__(self, *args, foo=None, **kwargs): super().__init__(*args, **kwargs); if foo is not None: self.p1 = f"{foo}_param_name1; ...`

Comment: @chepner Of course, `foo=None` also should work. A matter of style `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` And actually your way is looking smarter. Updated

Comment: By the way, `p1: Optional[str]` is just as important as calling `super().__init__` in getting `settings.p1 = ...` to work.

Comment: @rzlvmp oh geez, the first part of this, defining p1 as a class level attribute before __init__, is the missing piece of the puzzle! trying this now, and then will accept.